# SQL dynamic auto incrementing column in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I'm trying to write a stored procedure [SQL 2008] with a dynamic, auto incrementing column and the syntax for this has escaped me.

If I have a table called widget with a single column called widget_nm my goal is to

```
SELECT [???] AS widget_id, widget_nm FROM widget
```

and get the following result

```
widget_id | widget_nm
1         | bob
2         | sally
3         | fred
```

I remembered how to do this once, but my memory has failed me ... any advice?

Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've not mentioned what dialect of sql you're using,

If you're on mssql(Tsql) 2005+ use the [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function

Comment: He tagged the question as SQL Server 2008...also +1

Comment: I think that tag was added after I answered, that or I'm going blind :S

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in SQL Server 2005 and later:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY widget_nm) AS widget_id, widget_nm
FROM widget
ORDER BY widget_nm
```

which will number in order of widget_nm

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2005, this is [trivial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).